# Join itself where parent date between child dates

Tags: mysql

I am struggling with building a query that would take some rows from a table by IDs and then join rows from the same table where `start_date` and `end_date` are between parent `start_date`. Consider table like

events

```
| id | event_type_id | start_date | end_date |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 100 |
| 2 | 2 | 5 | 20 |
| 3 | 2 | 8 | 50 |
```

Events with `event_type_id` = 1 are like normal events while the ones with =2 are period events. I'd like to build query so I get all normal events, but along with period events that `start_date` and `end_date` are between normal event `start_date`. So considering example above I want to get event with `id` of 1 and join events with `event_type_id` of 2 with `start_date` and `end_date` between 10. Note that even though there is only 1 record with `event_type_id`=1 there would be more of them and I want to take all of them in one query. I know it is easy to do for single record, but I'd like to fetch like a whole tree of this so I won't end up with n+1. Is it even possible or should I think about different approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  e1.*,
  e2.*
FROM
  events e1 LEFT JOIN events e2
ON
  e1.start_date BETWEEN e2.start_date AND e2.end_date
AND
  e2.event_type_id=2
WHERE
  e1.event_type_id=1;
```